# libpng error: CgBI: unhandled critical chunk xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, image, cocos2d-x, libpng

After switching to Xcode 7.3, and running the project on the same, I got following error-

```
libpng error: CgBI: unhandled critical chunk
```

I have set `Compress PNG Files` in build setting of the projects target to `NO`.

I cleaned and rebuild the project, but still its not working and giving above error.

Any suggestions/help to resolve above issue is/are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apart from turning off `Compress PNG Files` flag in the build settings of the project target. I also turn off another flag, namely `Remove Texture Metadata from PNG File`. Doing so, resolved the issue **libpng error: CgBI: unhandled critical chunk** occuring in *Xcode 7.3*.

In *Xcode 7.3*, by default the flag `Remove Texture Metadata from PNG File` is turned on, so even if you have your project executing in earlier versions of the Xcode which contained this flag as set disabled, than also you need to again turn it off to overcome this issue.

Refer the screenshot below, showing the required flags to be turned off in build settings of the project target to resolve above issue in *Xcode 7.3.*

[image]

Comment: Apple has their own version of libpng and I know that compress actually means rearrange. I'll bet some feature they use isn't in official libpng.